# WSO2 EI split the huge file into a smaller file of 10,000 lines

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to split one large csv file into smaller files of 10000 lines.I don't know how to work with the input file on FS and memory usage has not increased too much and then to make the  csv file smaller.
if less than 10000 rows, only one rows file will be created
I tried to search on wso2 doc and google, but unfortunately I didn't find this tutorial anywhere.
i use WSO2 EI 6.5
can you help me please with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to split the CSV files, you can simply use the file connector. The document [1] contains the instructions to use the split file operation. You can specify the number of lines, source, and destination.

In addition to this, you can develop a class mediator project and develop the file split operation in a Java code.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-splitFile

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Class+Mediator

Answer (score 2):

Beside what Shanaka posted, you can also use SMOOKS to achive this. I've used it for splitting large XMLs into small parts. This works without any problems, maybe you want to give it a try.

More can be found e.g. here

[Smooks EI6.5 - XML](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Sample+658%3A+Huge+XML+Message+Processing+with+Smooks+Mediator)

[Smooks ESB 5.0 - TXT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+659%3A+Huge+EDI+Message+Processing+with+Smooks+Mediator)